# Loop through a temporary table and insert to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to insert the data in a csv file in to a temporary table and insert some data for the corresponding id value in another table. I have created and inserted the data in to the csv file. For all the records in the csv file how can I loop through and insert dome data for the corresponding record in the other table.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbcompanies
(ID INT)
GO

BULK
INSERT #tbcompanies
FROM 'd:\ids.csv'
WITH
(
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

select * from #tbcompanies

drop table #tbcompanies
```

Comment: Why do you think a loop is necessary? Can't you just `INSERT [other table] SELECT ID FROM #tbcompanies AS t /* perhaps some join to [yet another table]`?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming both tables have an ID column, you could update the other table like:

```
update  ot
set     col1 = tmp.col1
.       col2 = tmp.col2
from    @tbcompanies tmp
join    OtherTable ot
on      ot.ID = tmp.ID
```

If in addition to updating, you'd like to `insert` rows that do not exist, consider the [merge statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

```
; merge OtherTable as target
using   #tmpcompanies as source
on      target.id = source.id 
when    not matched by target then
        insert (id, col1, col2) values (source.id, source.col1, source.col2)
when    matched then
        update set col1 = source.col1, col2 = source.col2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually need to insert some new records. I will update my script.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop through anything, since you use SQL Server 2008 and this version supports the `MERGE` statement.

Have a look [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/).

Or simply use update with a from clause and join the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

If it's upsert functionality you need, I strongly recommend the [Merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) function.

pseudo code

```
   merge TargetTableName target
   using #tbcompanies tmp on tmp.idfield=target.idfield
   when matched then update......
   when not matched then insert...........
```